# How do display ObservedEthnicity for respondent?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml code with several CaseParties. I want to only display the ObservedEthnicity for the respondent. My xslt is displaying the ObservedEthnicity but for the first found CaseParty. 
How do I change it to display the ObservedEthnicity for the respondent?
**Here is my xml code**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com">
<Case InternalID="1616760296" ID="11683548" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <CaseParty ID="16548426" InternalCasePartyID="1633585331" InternalPartyID="1614451562">
        <ObservedRace Word="W">White</ObservedRace>
        <ObservedEthnicity Word="NH">Non Hispanic</ObservedEthnicity>
        <Connection Word="PET" BaseConnection="PL" ID="34645653" InternalCasePartyConnectionID="1635192840">
            <Description>Petitioner</Description>
        </Connection>
        <CasePartyName Current="true" ID="9638953" InternalNameID="1615263003">
            <FormattedName>Petitioner, Richard S</FormattedName>
        </CasePartyName>
    </CaseParty>
    <CaseParty ID="16548378" InternalCasePartyID="1633585333" InternalPartyID="1614451515">
        <ObservedRace Word="W">White</ObservedRace>
        <ObservedEthnicity Word="R">Refused</ObservedEthnicity>
        <Connection Word="CHL" BaseConnection="WA" ID="34645655" InternalCasePartyConnectionID="1635192842">
            <Description>Child (Family/Juv)</Description>
        </Connection>
        <CasePartyName Current="true" ID="9638891" InternalNameID="1615262953">
            <FormattedName>Dickens, Little</FormattedName>
        </CasePartyName>
    </CaseParty>
    <CaseParty ID="16548427" InternalCasePartyID="1633585332" InternalPartyID="1614451563">
        <ObservedRace Word="W">White</ObservedRace>
        <ObservedEthnicity Word="H">Hispanic</ObservedEthnicity>
        <Connection Word="RSP" BaseConnection="DF" ID="34645654" InternalCasePartyConnectionID="1635192841">
            <Description>Respondent</Description>
        </Connection>
        <CasePartyName Current="true" ID="9638954" InternalNameID="1615263004">
            <FormattedName>Respondent, Richard S</FormattedName>
        </CasePartyName>
    </CaseParty>
</Case>
```

**Here is my xslt code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://www.courts.state.dc.us/ProtectionOrderExtension/1.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="ProtectionOrder">
        <ext:ProtectionOrder>
            <xsl:variable name="vProtectionOrderID">
                <xsl:value-of select="@InternalProtectionOrderID"/>
            </xsl:variable>
<!--Respondent Address-->
            <xsl:for-each select="RespondentAddresses/Address">
                <xsl:call-template name="Location"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
<!--ext:ProtectionOrderID-->
            <ext:ProtectionOrderID>
                <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderNumber"/>
            </ext:ProtectionOrderID>
<!--Respondent-->
            <xsl:for-each select="RespondentPartyID">
                <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID) and (Connection[(@Word='RSP') ])]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                        <xsl:call-template name="Respondent">
                            <xsl:with-param name="pProtectionOrderID">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$vProtectionOrderID"/>
                            </xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ext:ProtectionOrder>
    </xsl:template>
<!--Respondent Template-->
    <xsl:template name="Respondent">
        <xsl:param name="pProtectionOrderID"/>
        <ext:Respondent>
            <nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="//CaseParty[@ID=current()/@ID]/ObservedEthnicity/@Word='NH'">N</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:if test="//CaseParty/ObservedEthnicity[@Word!='R']">
                            <xsl:value-of select="//CaseParty/ObservedEthnicity/@Word"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
        </ext:Respondent>
        <ext:RespondentPresentAtHearingIndicator>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/ProtectionOrder/MNProtectionOrderAdditional/IsRespondentPresent"/>
        </ext:RespondentPresentAtHearingIndicator>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Something is missing at the end of XML code

Comment: Well, when I run your stylesheet, I don't get what you say ...

Comment: I have added the part that I had excluded at the bottom of xml code. Is that helpful?

Comment: Could you post the exact output that you do want? -- Also, will there always be only one respondent in the input?

Comment: I think I have resolved this one. I am getting the correct output. However, what do I need to change in the xslt so that when <nc:PersonEthnicityCode>R</nc:PersonEthnicityCode> this should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get the output I wanted. However I now want to change it so if the xml has the following element with R then it should not display.

```
<ObservedEthnicity Word="R">Refused</ObservedEthnicity>
```

**The observedEthnicity in xml is the same as PersonEthnicityCode in xslt**

**When this is the case I do not want to display it. This is reflected in my xslt as**

```
<nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//CaseParty[@ID=current()/@ID]/ObservedEthnicity/@Word='NH'">N</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="//CaseParty/ObservedEthnicity/@Word"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
```

**What I did xslt code (one line)**

```
<nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//CaseParty[@ID=current()/@ID]/ObservedEthnicity/@Word='NH'">N</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="//CaseParty/ObservedEthnicity/@Word"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
```

Comment: How can I change my xslt code so that when xml document has an element ObservedEthnicity with **R** it is not displayed. Example if xml document has this element, it should not be displayed `<ObservedEthnicity Word="R">Refused</ObservedEthnicity>`

Comment: Here is the output I am getting which is wrong. `<ext:Respondent>
<nc:PersonEthnicityCode>N</nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
<ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">1966-01-02</ext:PersonBirthDate>
<ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="false">1966-02-02</ext:PersonBirthDate>
<ext:PersonName ext:currentIndicator="true">
<nc:PersonFullName>Respondent, Richard S</nc:PersonFullName>
</ext:PersonName>
</ext:Respondent>` **Instead I should get** `<nc:PersonEthnicityCode>H</nc:PersonEthnicityCode>` that's respondent code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to put an xsl:if around the nc:PersonEthnicityCode. Something like:

```
<!-- assume exactly one ObservedEthnicity -->
<!-- Significance of ObservedEthnicity's text() nodes not clear; just using @Word. -->
<xsl:variable name="observed-ethnicity-word" 
              select="//CaseParty[@ID=current()/@ID]/ObservedEthnicity/@Word">
<xsl:if test"$observed-ethnicity-word != 'R'">
  <nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$observed-ethnicity-word = 'NH'">N</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$observed-ethnicity-word"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </nc:PersonEthnicityCode>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks Rober. I tried it but I was getting an error about this being empty. `<xsl:variable name="observed-ethnicity-word"            select="//CaseParty[@ID=current()/@ID]/ObservedEthnicity/@Word">` I am using 3.0 for xml